# Arc Tangents and Equation

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

For one of the problems in my book, it requires you to put the arc tangent into the 2piK equation and solve for the arc tangents and lie in [0,2pi].  For:

arctan(117)+piK

the answers are 1.5622 and 4.70384, how is the 4.70384 found??

Answer (score 2):

$1.5622+\pi\approx 4.70384{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Adding or subtracting any other multiples of $\pi$ gives you values outside of the range $[0,2\pi]$, so those are the only answers.